# What is "ovs-testc"? How Do I Disable It?

Tags: networking, virtualization, services

I'd like to run an SDN application on my Ubuntu machine (ver 22.04.3 LTS).  As I understand it, when the SDN runs, it needs to BIND to TCP 6653, the default port for OVS.  But on my machine, the SDN application bombs out, because another process has already BIND'ed to TCP 6653:

```
me@ubunbtu1:~$ sudo lsof -i :6653
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ovs-testc 1101 root    3u  IPv4  22990      0t0  TCP *:6653 (LISTEN)
me@ubunbtu1:~$
```

So what is "ovs-testc"?  I originally assumed that it was "openvswitch-testcontroller", but a few Google searches produced conflicting results.  I found that I could "kill -9 1101" on this service, that that seems like a heavy-handed approach.  I'd like to understand more about what this process is, and how to turn it off gracefully.

Whatever "ovs-testc" is, its persistent.  Below are some of my fruitless attempts to disable it.

Can anyone give me some info about this process?  Where does it come from?  How to I disable it?  Thank you.

```
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$ sudo service --status-all | grep openvswitch
 [ + ]  openvswitch-switch
 [ + ]  openvswitch-testcontroller
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$ sudo lsof -i :6653
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ovs-testc 1166 root    3u  IPv4  23255      0t0  TCP *:6653 (LISTEN)
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$ sudo systemctl disable openvswitch-testcontroller
openvswitch-testcontroller.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable openvswitch-testcontroller
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$ sudo systemctl disable openvswitch-switch
Synchronizing state of openvswitch-switch.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable openvswitch-switch
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/openvswitch-switch.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/openvswitch-switch.service.requires/ovs-record-hostname.service.
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$ sudo service --status-all | grep openvswitch
 [ + ]  openvswitch-switch
 [ + ]  openvswitch-testcontroller
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$ sudo lsof -i :6653
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ovs-testc 1166 root    3u  IPv4  23255      0t0  TCP *:6653 (LISTEN)
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$ GAH!!!!
GAHsudo lsof -i :6653sudo lsof -i :6653
-bash: GAHsudo: command not found
me@ubuntu1:~$
me@ubuntu1:~$
```

Comment: Are you trying to **stop** the service? AFAIK `disable` only does that on next boot - from the `disable` section of `man systemctl`: *Note that this command does not implicitly stop the units that are being disabled. If this is desired, either combine this command with the --now switch, or invoke the stop command with appropriate arguments later.*

Comment: @steeldriver You're right!  The `openvswitch` services appeared as disabled after I rebooted the Ubuntu.  I didn't know that - thanks!